# @Html.AntiForgeryToken() casuses "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error in Chrome and crash pagea after several reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, antiforgerytoken

I have a view with a form generated by Html.BeginForm helper and Html.AntiForgeryToken inside.
Generaly the view contains a quite complicated table with subtables.
It works as expected for low amount of rows (approximatelly lower that 1000 main rows).

I noticed that when some amount of rows is exceeded (I can't precisly say how many) the below error occurs:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

and the request is resend to the server ...

and again `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

up to four or five times and it finally crashes

[image]
[image]

I found out that when I do only one thing - comment the line with AntiForgeryToken:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
...
```

it works for every amount of rows.

To be precise: the form with AntiForgeryToken is repeted in every table row.

Of course I don't want to stop using AntiForgeryToken but cannot find the original reason why in causes this error.